# Create Surface over Hair Curves Blender 3.3.1

Tags: nurbs-surface

This is my first time using blender, I am trying to make a face and 3D print it. I have made the hair using blender's built in hair feature (the "empty hair" under curves). I modify it a bit to add some noise and duplicate the hairs. However, these curves cannot be 3D printed. I would like to create a surface over this hair so I can print it.

I've tried converting the hair into a mesh and trying to shrinkwrap a NURBs surface over it, but I am unable to select the hair mesh to shrinkwrap to.

[image: the model]

This is my ending geometry node sequence, which makes the curves into a mesh (everything before just modifies the hair curves)

[image: ending sequence]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: With the nodes shown above the curves will be converted only into edges because the *Profile Curves* slot is empty. You can plug in a Curve Circle but this will create a lot of geometry. I'm not sure if the shrink wrap will work as you expect it to. I would sculpt the hair.

Comment: I see! Plugging in a Curve Circle (and decreasing the resolution of the splines so the 3D printing program didn't crash) allowed me to actually export to a 3D printing program. Thanks so much! Blender is hard...